# How to insert a node in specific index

Tags: java, data-structures

First of all pardon me if the way I'm asking is wrong, I'm new at programming and still need a lot of learning, here is my code
This is my Node class

```
public class Node
{

int value;
Node link;

void setValue(int a){
value = a;
}

int getValue(){
return value;
}

void setNode(Node i){
link = i;
}

Node getNode(){
return link;
}
}
```

And this one my NodeContainer class

```
    public class NodeContainer
{
Node tail;
Node head;

void setHead(int i){
    Node a = new Node();
    a.setValue(i);
    head = a;
    tail = head;
}

Node getHead(){
    return head;

}

void addNode(int i){
    Node a = new Node();
    a.setValue(i);

    tail.setNode(a);
    tail = a;
}

void addNode(int i,int index){
Node a = new Node();
a.setValue(i);
int c = 1;
Node temp = head;
Node first = head;
   while(head!=null){  
    head = head.getNode();
    if(c==index-1){
        a.setNode(head.getNode());
        temp = head;
        temp.setNode(a);
    }
    c++;
}
head = first;
head.setNode(temp);
}

int count(){
int c = 1;
boolean have = true;
if(head!=null){
while(head.getNode()!=null){       
    c++;
    head = head.getNode();
}
    return c;
}
else{
have = false;
return 0;}
} 

}
```

i just cant think a way to insert a node in spesific index, i tried it on addNode method have tried so many ways i can think of but it cant work, thanks in advance

Comment: If you are trying to create a linked list you can add a node by setting it's next element to the one you want and updating previous to point toward your new node. (It seems not clear but I can't find a way to formulate better ^^)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a node at a specific position in a Linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640749/inserting-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

You do not need to keep track of the tail (necessarily) I see you are new to linked lists, so perhaps try to master the basics before adding extra features.

Also, try adding some white space in your code, it makes it easier to read.

I heavily commented the section that covers inserting at a specified index. put all these files in the same folder, the compile it. You should get the output that follows:

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
inserting -1 at position 5
0 1 2 3 4 -1 5 6 7 8 9
```

Main class:

```
class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    NodeContainer linkedList = new NodeContainer();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      linkedList.addNode(i);
    }

    display(linkedList.head);

    // NOTE - indexes start at 0, not 1
    System.out.println("inserting -1 at position 5");

    linkedList.addNode(-1, 5);

    display(linkedList.head);

  }

  public static void display(Node node) {
    while (node != null) {
      System.out.print(node.value + " ");

      node = node.link;
    }

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Node Container class:

```
public class NodeContainer {
  public Node head;
  public int size;

  public NodeContainer() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
  }

  public void addNode(int i) {
    Node node = new Node(i);

    if (head == null) {
      head = node;

    } else {
      Node temp;

      temp = head;

      while (temp.link != null) {

      temp = temp.link;

      }
      temp.link = node;
    }

    size++;
  }

  public void addNode(int i, int index) {
    Node node;
    Node temp;
    int count;

    // If we want to insert
    // into the front of the list
    if (index == 0) {

      // User a constructor instead of
      // making a new node every time,
      // then typing set value
      node = new Node(i);
      node.link = head;
      head = node;

      // If the index is within the linkedlist
    } else if (index > 0 && index < size) {

      count = 0;
      temp = head;

      // Keep looking until the index prior to
      // the one we want to insert at
      while(temp.link != null && count < size) {

        // Once we find it, break out the loop
        if (count == index-1) {
          break;
        }

        // Keep traversing the list
        temp = temp.link;

        // increment counter
        count++;
      }

      // Instantiate the node
      node = new Node(i);

      // Point this node's link to
      // the n-1th node's link
      node.link = temp.link;

      // Set n-1th node's next to this
      // node (effectively putting it
      // in position n)
      temp.link = node;

      // Otherwise don't do anything
    } else {
      ;
    }

  }

}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node {

  public int value;
  public Node link;

  // User a constructor
  public Node(int i) {

    value = i;
    link = null;
  }

  public void setValue(int a) {
    value = a;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setNode(Node i) {
    link = i;
  }

  public Node getNode() {
    return link;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your original code snippet to be like this :

```
public class Node
{
    int value;
    Node next;

    void setValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    void setNext(Node next){
        this.next = next;
    }

    Node getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }
}

 public class NodeContainer {

    Node tail;
    Node head;

    void setHead(int i) {
        Node a = newNode(i);

        head = a;
        tail = a;
    }

    private Node newNode(int value) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.setValue(i);
        return node;
    }

    void addNode(int i) {
        Node a = newNode(i);

        Node tmp = this.head;
        while(tmp.getNext() != null){
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
        tmp.setNext(a);
        tail = a;
    }

    void addNode(int value, int index) {
        //TODO : add check on head
        Node a = newNode(value);

        Node tmp = this.head;
        int i = 0;
        while(tmp.getNext()!=null && i < index) {
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
            i++;
        }

        //TODO : add check on tmp
        Node next = tmp.getNext();
        tmp.setNext(a);
        a.setNext(next);
    }

    int count() {
        //...
    }

}
```